# How to use readline() method in Java?

Tags: java, io, readline

I am beginner in Java, and I was reading the topic of giving values to variables through the `readLine()` method from the keyboard. The program for that is given in the book is as follows:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream
class Reading
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        int intnumber=0;
        float floatnumber=0.0f;
        try {
            system.out.println("enter an integer: ");
            intnumber = Integer.parseInt(in.readline());

            system.out.println("enter a float number: ");
            floatnumber = Float.valueOf(in.readline()).floatvalue();
        }

        // Rest of code
```

I want to ask the following questions:

1. What is done in the following statement?

   ```
   DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
   ```

   If `in` is an object of `DataInputStream` then what is new and what do the statement on the right-hand side of above statement do?
2. Why have different methods been used for putting the integer value into intnumber and float value into floatnumber?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I advise you to go with `Scanner` instead of `DataInputStream`. `Scanner` is specifically designed for this purpose and introduced in Java 5. See the following links to know how to use `Scanner`.

- [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)
- [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html)

Example

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(s.nextInt());
System.out.println(s.nextInt());
System.out.println(s.next());
System.out.println(s.next());
```

Answer (score 32):

Use BufferedReader and InputStreamReader classes.

```
BufferedReader buffer=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line=buffer.readLine();
```

Or use `java.util.Scanner` class methods.

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 6):

In summary: I would be careful as to what code you copy. It is possible you are copying code which happens to work, rather than well chosen code.

> In intnumber, parseInt is used and in floatnumber valueOf is used why so?

There is no good reason I can see. It's an inconsistent use of the APIs as you suspect.

---

Java is case sensitive, and there isn't any `Readline()` method. Perhaps you mean readLine().

DataInputStream.readLine() is deprecated in favour of using BufferedReader.readLine();

However, for your case, I would use the Scanner class.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int intNum = sc.nextInt();
float floatNum = sc.nextFloat();
```

If you want to know what a class does I suggest you have a quick look at [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 6):

A `DataInputStream` is just a decorator over an `InputStream` (which `System.in` is) which allows to read using more convenient methods.

As to the `Float.valueOf()`, well, that's curious because `Float` has `.parseFloat()` as well. Here the code grabs a `Float` with `.valueOf()` which it turns into the primitive `float` type using `.floatValue()`, which is unnecessary with Java 1.5+ due to auto unboxing.

And as other answers rightly say, these methods are obsolete anyway.

Answer (score 4):

This will explain it, I think...

```
import java.io.*;

class reading
{
    public static void  main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        float number;
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        try
        {
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
            String a = br.readLine();
            number = Float.valueOf(a);
            int x = (int)number;

            System.out.println("Your input=" + number);
            System.out.println("Your input in integer terms is = " + x);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```