# how to create a square using for loops

Tags: java, algorithm, text, for-loop

I need help making a program where you allow the user to enter a character and a number and output a square on the screen which consists of the character with sides equal to the number entered.

e.g. User enters $ and 5 – and outputs

```
            $$$$$
            $   $
            $   $
            $   $
            $$$$$
```

I tried this so far, but I don't know how to get rid of the characters inside the box.

```
int r,c;
System.out.println (" Please enter the number of rows for the rectangle.");
r=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println (" Please enter a character for the rectangle.");
c=sc.nextInt();
for (int x=r;x>=1;--x) {
    for (int y=r;y>=1;y--) {
        System.out.print (c);
    }
    System.out.println (c);
}
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.** See the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/172661).

Comment: Please post which language you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said about your example that you don't know how to get rid of the characters in the box.
I believe the best way to get rid of something you don't want is to not put it there in the first place. Let's think about your problem a little.

Based on your example, you want a square box of characters enclosing some whitespace, correct?
This fundamentally breaks down into two different lines.
These are the two horizontal edges and the `r-2` vertical edges.

We can build a simple algorithm from this.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int r;
String c;
String h, v;

// Get input from the user.
System.out.println("Please enter the number of rows for the rectangle.");
r = s.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter a character for the rectangle.");
c = s.next();

// Make the box's lines.
h =     new String(new char[r  ]).replace("\0",  c);
v = c + new String(new char[r-2]).replace("\0", " ") + c;

System.out.println(h);
for (int i=r-2; i>=1; --i) {
    System.out.println(v);
}
System.out.println(h);
```

For a little more material on repeating strings, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1235179/828255), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8560395/828255) for user input in Java. I hope this has been of some help. I leave handling squares of size `r<2` as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: thanks i get it , but how do you now let the user enter both the character of their choose and the dimensions for the sqaure?

Comment: @user3006901: You will need to use something like [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). I recommend reading the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) on it. I've edited my answer to reflect how it could be used for your situatioon.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c = '$';
int n = 5;

for (int i=0,m=n+1; i<m*n; ++i) {
    putchar(i%m==n?'\n':(i+m)%(m*n)<2*m?c:(i+m+2)%m<3?c:' ');
}
```