# Get data from console in string

Tags: java

I am trying to retrieve a string from my console with `System.console().readline();`
but when i run the program to get the string it throws a exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How can i get data from my console and put it in a string?
This is what i tried:

```
String response = System.console().readline();
System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: Try using a Scanner, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html. You can create a new Scanner(Systsem.in) and then get strings with .next() (and check if input is available with .hasNext())

Comment: Do you want to read input ? or any text ?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560395/how-to-use-readline-in-java

Comment: System.console() returns null in an IDE, so if you really need to use System.console(), read this solution from McDowell.http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.in/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `Scanner` for this purpose.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String st = sc.next();
```

You can use `sc.nextInt()` to get integer value from console.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are developing a very specific application, the `Console` object returned by `System.console()` is not the one you should use to retrieve user input.

This is `System.console()` definition:

```
 /**
 * Returns the unique {@link java.io.Console Console} object associated
 * with the current Java virtual machine, if any.
 *
 * @return  The system console, if any, otherwise <tt>null</tt>.
 *
 * @since   1.6
 */
 public static Console console() {
     if (cons == null) {
         synchronized (System.class) {
             cons = sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaIOAccess().console();
         }
     }
     return cons;
 }
```

It may return `null`: *Returns the unique object associated with the current Java virtual machine,* **if any.**

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) you can find the reason why it can be `null`:

> Whether a virtual machine has a console is dependent upon the underlying platform and also upon the manner in which the virtual machine is invoked. If the virtual machine is started from an interactive command line without redirecting the standard input and output streams then its console will exist and will typically be connected to the keyboard and display from which the virtual machine was launched. If the virtual machine is started automatically, for example by a background job scheduler, then it will typically not have a console.

As other answers and comments suggest, you should use `System.in`, being `Scanner` an easy to use tool to read lines and tokens.

Comment: Nice explanation why it doesn't work!