# Java.lang.String[] as an incompatible type?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
package com.example.mohammed.flagquizgameapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.lang.String;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    // String used when logging error messages
    private static final String TAG = "FlagQuizGame Activity";

    private List<String> fileNameList; // flag file names
    private List<String> quizCountriesList; //name of countries in quiz
    private Map<String, Boolean> regionsMap; // which regions are enabled
    private String correctAnswer; // correct country for the current flag
    private int totalGuesses; // number of guesses made
    private int correctAnswers; // number of correct guesses
    private int guessRows; // number of rows displaying choices
    private Random random; //random number generator
    private Handler handler; // used to delay loading next flag
    private Animation shakeAnimation; // animation for incorrect guess

    private TextView answerTextView; // displays Correct! or Incorrect!
    private TextView questionNumberTextView; // shows current question #
    private ImageView flagImageView; // displays a flag
    private TableLayout buttonTableLayout; // table of answer Buttons

    // called when the activity is first created
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // call the superclass's method
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // inflate the GUI

        fileNameList = new ArrayList<String>(); // list of flag names
        quizCountriesList = new ArrayList<String>(); // flags in this quiz
        regionsMap = new HashMap<String, Boolean>(); // HashMap of regions
        guessRows = 1; // default to one row of choices
        random = new Random(); // initialize the random number generator
        handler = new Handler(); // used to perform delayed operations

        // load the shake animation that's used for incorrect answers
        shakeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.incorrect_shake);
        shakeAnimation.setRepeatCount(3); // animation repeats 3 times

        // get array of world regions from strings.xml
        String[] regionNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.regionsList);

        // by default, countries are chosen from all regions
        for (String region : regionNames)
            regionsMap.put(region, true);

        // get references to GUI components
        questionNumberTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionNumberTextView);
        flagImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flagImageView);
        buttonTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonTableLayout);
        answerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);

        // set questionNumberTextView's text
        questionNumberTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.question) + "1"
                + getResources().getString(R.string.of) + "10");

        resetQuiz(); // start a new quiz
    } // end method onCreate
    // set up and start the new quiz
    private void resetQuiz()
    {
        // use the AssetManager to get the image flag
        // file names for only the enabled regions
        AssetManager assets = getAssets(); // gets the app's AssetManager
        fileNameList.clear(); // empty the list

        try{
            Set<String> regions = regionsMap.keySet(); // get Set of regions

            // loop through each region
            for(String region: regions) //if region is enabled
            {
                if(regionsMap.get(region)) {
                    //get a list of all the flag image files in this region
                    String[] paths = assets.list(region);

                    for(String path: paths)
                        fileNameList.add(path.replace(".png", ""));

                } // end if
            } // end for
        }// end try
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error loading image file names", e);
        } // end catch

        correctAnswers = 0; // reset the number of correct answers made
        totalGuesses = 0; // reset the total number of guesses the user made
        quizCountriesList.clear(); // clear prior list of quiz countries
    } // end method resetquiz

    // after the user guesses a correct flag, load the next flag
    private void loadNextFlag() throws IOException
    {
        // get the file name of the next flag and remove it from the list
        String nextImageName = quizCountriesList.remove(0);
        correctAnswer = nextImageName; // update the correct answer

        answerTextView.setText(""); // clear answerTextView

        // display the number of the current question in the quiz
        questionNumberTextView.setText(
               getResources().getString(R.string.question) + " " + (correctAnswers + 1) + " " +
               getResources().getString(R.string.of) + " 10");

        // extract the region from the next image's name
        String region = nextImageName.substring(0, nextImageName.indexOf('-'));

        // use AssetManager to load next image from the assets folder
        AssetManager assets = getAssets(); // get app's AssetManager
        InputStream stream; // used to read in flag images

        try{
            // get an InputStream to the asset representing the next flag
            stream = assets.open(region + "/" + nextImageName + ".png");]

            // load the asset as a Drawable and display on the flagImageView
            Drawable flag = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, nextImageName);
            flagImageView.setImageDrawable(flag);
        } // end try
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error loading " + nextImageName, e);
        } // end catch

        // clear prior answer Buttons from TableRows
        for(int row = 0; row < buttonTableLayout.getChildCount(); ++row)
            ((TableRow) buttonTableLayout.getChildAt(row)).removeAllViews();

        Collections.shuffle(fileNameList); // shuffle file names

        // put the correct answer at the end of fileNameList
        int correct = fileNameList.indexOf(correctAnswer);
        fileNameList.add(fileNameList.remove(correct));

        // get a reference to the LayoutInflater service
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // add 3, 6, or 9 answer Buttons based on the value of guessRows
        for(int row = 0; row < guessRows; row++)
        {
            TableRow currentTableRow = getTableRow(row);

            // place Buttons in currentTableRow
            for(int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
            {
                // inflate guess_button.xml to create new button
                Button newGuessButton = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.guess_button, null);

                // get country name and set it as newGuessButton's text
                String fileName = fileNameList.get((row*3) + column);
                newGuessButton.setText(getCountryName(fileName));

                // register answerButtonListener to respond to button clicks
                newGuessButton.setOnClickListener(guessButtonListener);
                currentTableRow.addView(newGuessButton);
            } // end for
        } // end for

        // randomly replace one Button with the correct answer
        int row = random.nextInt(guessRows); // pick random row
        int column = random.nextInt(3);// pick random column
        TableRow randomTableRow = getTableRow(row); // get the TableRow
        String countryName = getCountryName(correctAnswer);
        ((Button) randomTableRow.getChildAt(column)).setText(countryName);
    } // end method loadNextFlag

    // returns the specified TableRow
    private TableRow getTableRow(int row)
    {
        return (TableRow) buttonTableLayout.getChildAt(row);
    } // end method getTableRow

    // parses the country flag file name and reurns the country name
    private String getCountryName(String name) {
        return name.substring(name.indexOf('-') + 1).replace('_', ' ');
    } // end method getCountryName

    // called when the user selects an answer
    private void submitGuess(Button guessButton)
    {
        String guess = guessButton.getText().toString();
        String answer = getCountryName(correctAnswer);
        ++totalGuesses; // increment the number of guesses the user has made


        // if the guess is correct
        if(guess.equals(answer))
        {
            ++correctAnswers; // increment the number of correct answers

            // display "Correct!" in green text
            answerTextView.setText(answer + "!");
            answerTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.correct_answer));

            disableButtons(); // disable all answer Buttons

            // if the user has correctly identified 10 flags
            if (correctAnswers == 10)
            {
                // create a new AlertDialog Builder
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                builder.setTitle(R.string.reset_quiz); // title bar string

                // set the AlertDialog's message to display game results
                builder.setMessage(String.format("%d %s, %.02f%% %s", totalGuesses, getResources().getString(R.string.guesses),
                        (1000 / (double) totalGuesses), getResources().getString(R.string.correct)));

                builder.setCancelable(false);

                // add "Reset Quiz" Button
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_quiz, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                            {
                                resetQuiz();
                            } // end method onClick
                     } // end anonymous inner class
                ); // end call to setPositiveButton

                //create AlertDialog for the Builder
                AlertDialog resetDialog = builder.create();
                resetDialog.show(); // display the Dialog
            } // end if
            else // answer is correct but quiz is not over
            {
                  // load the next flag after a 1-second delay
                handler.postDelayed(
                        new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                loadNextFlag();
                            }
                        }, 1000); // 1000 milliseconds for 1-second delay
            } // end else
        } // end if
        else // guess was incorrect
        {
            // play the animation
            flagImageView.startAnimation(shakeAnimation);

            // display "Incorrect!" in red
            answerTextView.setText(R.string.incorrect_answer);
            answerTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.incorrect_answer));
            guessButton.setEnabled(false); // disable the incorrect answer
        } // end else
    } // end method submitGuess

    // utility method that disables all answer Buttons
    private void disableButtons()
    {
        for(int row = 0; row < buttonTableLayout.getChildCount(); ++row)
        {
            TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) buttonTableLayout.getChildAt(row);
            for(int i = 0; i < tableRow.getChildCount(); ++i)
                tableRow.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
        } // end outer for
    } // end method disableButtons

    // create constants for each menu id
    private final int CHOICES_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private final int REGIONS_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    // called when the user accesses the options menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        // add two options to the menu - "Choices" and "Regions"
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, CHOICES_MENU_ID, Menu.NONE, R.string.choices);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, REGIONS_MENU_ID, Menu.NONE, R.string.regions);

        return true; // display the menu
    } // end method onCreateOptionsMenu


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // switch the men id of the user-selected option
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case CHOICES_MENU_ID:
                // create a list of the possible numbers of animal choices
                final String[] possibleChoices = getResources().getString(R.array.guessesList);

                //
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The above code has a String[] inside a switch statement. The error that I get from this code is as follows:

Incompatible types
Required: java.lang.String[]
Found: java.lank.String

I'm pretty confused by this. I tried searching it online, but only got results that java.lang.string is found but int is required.

Comment: Why do you post 200 lines of unrelated code?

Comment: You passed a single string where it expected an array.  If you only want to pass it the one string, pass it an array of size one with that string in it.

Comment: I put the entire code because, from past experience, if I make a small mistake on the polar side of the code, it changes the entire result. Just a precaution..

Comment: _Just a precaution_ indicates that you haven't made the effort necessary to identify the error. Please take the tour and read the help center to understand what we expect form you on Stack Overflow. Read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Turns out the problem wasn't with the rest of the code, which I did go through. I'm not a professional while you guys are, so I just needed a double check. Thanks anyways for the link.

Comment: It has nothing to do with professionalism. It has to do with effort. I don't see any on your part in your question. This error is so well documented online. You can search for _incompatible type errors_ and find the answer a hundred times over. [Here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279789/java-args-incompatible-types). I'm out of votes.

Comment: This is the first app I made, and as a 13-year old I don't exactly have the surge of motivation nor the experience to suggest to myself that I can just find an error. I won't even know what the error is and what to search for. As a matter of fact, I did see that question (the link you gave) and I did apply it, and it didn't really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
final String[] possibleChoices = getResources().getString(R.array.guessesList);
```

to

```
final String[] possibleChoices = new String[] { getResources().getString(R.array.guessesList)};
```

> Incompatible types Required: java.lang.String[] Found:
>   java.lang.String

the `possibleChoices` object is expecting an array, not an `Integer`.

Comment: You get an upvote for having the patience to dig through all that code

Comment: Well, we're here to help, so... xD Plus he did specify that the error was inside a `switch` statement..

Comment: This did the job for that problem. But then I get another problem, saying that (R.array.guessesList) is the wrong use for the resource. Don't feel obliged to answer. Thanks for the first answer.

Comment: @MohammedIbrahim make sure that you are defining a `string-array` of resources with the **guessesList** `id`.

Comment: Check these links, http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-essentials-working-with-strings-and-string-arrays--mobile-7838 they shall get you started. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: Woops. Typo. Java.lang.String