# Why is the only thing in my array the last line of the file?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program where I have to transfer all the data of a file to an array, line by line. When I display the line though, the only thing in the array is the last line. I need the array to have all the lines of the file so I can select an index of the array.

Here is the code so far,

```
 while(inputFileTest.hasNext()) //counts amount of lines in the file
{
  count++;
  inputFileTest.nextLine();
}
fileTest= new File("TestBank.txt");
inputFileTest= new Scanner(fileTest);
String[] testArr=new String[count];

while(inputFileTest.hasNext()) 
{
  int i=0;
  String line= inputFileTest.nextLine(); 
  testArr= line.split("\n");
  testArr[i]=testArr[0];
  i++;
}
//int i=rand.nextInt(testArr.length);
for(String test:testArr)
  System.out.println(test);
```

}
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use readline() method in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560395/how-to-use-readline-method-in-java)

Answer (score 5):

```
while(inputFileTest.hasNext()) 
{
  int i=0;
```

Should be

```
 int i=0;
while(inputFileTest.hasNext()) 
{
```

You are setting it to zero all the time. Move that to top of while loop, and you'd be fine.

And also, as bastijn commented , you are ovveriding the array too. so it should be

```
  String[] ta= line.split("\n");
  testArr[i]=ta[0];
```

Comment: He is also overwriting testArr inside his loop (with line.split output). Care to update your answer to include that?

Comment: Thanks. Removed my answer. One is enough for these questions :).

Comment: Welcome. If it worked you can accept the answer. Cheers.