# How I do make Scanner class reads my complete String input

Tags: java, string

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = sc.next();

System.out.println(str);
```

```
Provided input : this is a good school
Obtained Output : this
```

Why is the complete string is not printing?

Answer (score 6):

Because [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) returns the next token, not complete line.

You can use

```
String str = sc.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of `Scanner.next()`:

> The java.util.Scanner.next() method finds and returns the next
>   complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and
>   followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm

If you want to read the entire line it is probably better to use this code:

```
BufferedReader buffer=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line=buffer.readLine();
```

Taken from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8560432/481528